# ¿Cómo hago para poner un cartel en css?

Tags: html, css

Pues quiero hacer como un "cartelito" dentro de un div en mi web, pero la verdad no sé como hacerlo

si la imagen se puede apreciar, lo que necesito hacer y no sé como es ese cartelito que hay en la parte superior izquierda (edite la imagen) en 45° y que dentro se pueda poner un texto

Si me pueden decir el método de como hacerlo y yo lo googleo estaría muy agredecido

Comment: Hola El nene aprende a programar, se puede hacer pero debes mostrarnos que has intentado o que has investigado :)

Comment: Por si sirve puedes buscar la propiedad `transform` de css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No hace falta usar un div especificamente para el rotulo, se puede hacer con :before

```css
.content:before{
    content:"texto";
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    z-index: 100;
    left: -33px;
    width: 140px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #666;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1e5799), color-stop(1%, #e09013), color-stop(100%, #e5b300));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
}
.content{
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
 Lo que sea
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Que pasaría si necesito HTML en el rótulo?

Comment: Tendrías que cambiar el `content:` por javascript, pero solo admite textos e imágenes, no permite tags. Este sistema tiene la ventaja de no necesitar marcado adicional en el html pero no se tiene mucho control. De hecho, puestos a cambiar el texto con js se podría inyectar el div directamente con un prepend (o .append) de jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Debes jugar con las propiedades `transform` de css3, usando `rotate` para inclinar tu cartelito y asignarle la propiedad `overflow: hidden` para que se oculten los sobrantes del div rotado.

Para saber más sobre la propiedad `transform` checa [este enlace de la W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Buscando encontré un snippet que te puede servir como guía:

```css
.offer{
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    z-index: 100;
    left: -33px;
    width: 140px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #666;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1e5799), color-stop(1%, #e09013), color-stop(100%, #e5b300));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #e09013 1%, #e5b300 100%);
}
.content{
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="offer">Texto</div>
</div>
```

*El snippet se encuentra en la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804881/rotated-div-comes-out-over-its-parent-div) de la comunidad de Stackoverflow en inglés.*